# Scala: function with no arguments

Tags: scala, lambda

Im relatively new to scala functions and I'm getting confused on how this syntax sugar actually works and when to use a particular type.

I have written 3 functions all which should do the same thing, but  I'm having problems understanding why Function0 is behaving differently

version 1

```
val fn1 : (String) => String = System.getProperty(_)

println(fn1("os.name"));
```

version 2

```
  val fn2 : () => String = System.getProperty("os.name")

  println(fn2());
```

Version 2 gives type mismatch; found : String required: () ⇒ String

version 3

```
val fn3 = () => System.getProperty("os.name")

println(fn3());
```

I understand that for version 2 scala already knows the return type of System.getProperty but  why does it produce that particular error, why does it prevent me form explicitly stating the return type. I personally prefer explicit return types so I don't have to dive into a method to see what it is returning.

Answer (score 4):

In `val fn2 : () => String = System.getProperty("os.name")`, the `System.getProperty("os.name")` will be executed and return a string value. But you are saying `fn2` is a value, which is a function that takes no arguments and returns a string.

When you do `System.getProperty(_)`, it is like doing `x => System.getProperty(x)`, which is a function that takes a string and returns a string. That is why first version works.

Comment: Sorry for the late response on this if the second functions is interpreted as "a value, which is a function that takes no argument and returns a string.  Wouldn't the first function be read in a similar way i.e. returns a function that takes a string and returns a string.   Instead the compiler figures out that you ant to return a string not a function.

Answer (score 1):

This version will typecheck:

```
val fn2 : () => String = () => System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Calling `fn2()` here is just like calling:

```
def fn2(): String = System.getProperty("os.name")
fn2()
```

In your `fn1` example, the underscore is providing this implicit syntax, which looks a lot more like what you need for the empty-args case:

```
val fn1 : (String) => (String) = (s) => System.getProperty(s)
```

Comment: `def`s are methods, which are not first class objects, contrary to FunctionN. So `val fn2: () => String` is definitely not the same thing as `def fn2(): String`.

Comment: Edited my answer for clarity.  In the OP's example, the two models I've written are equivalent.  `def`s cannot be passed as objects, but I think this comparison is still helpful.